# Removing SharePoint list MySite Personal Documents in Outlook for all users

Tags: document-library, outlook, sharepoint-library

We are phasing out SharePoint 2007. The problem is that some users have links to the SharePoint library "My Site- Personal Documents" in their outlook. When removing permissions on SP2007 these users are getting log-on boxes in Outlook. I know how to remove the library connection manually, but is there a way to do this for all users from a central location?